# How to Refresh the embedded Google Data Studio report on demand?

Tags: api, google-bigquery, data-visualization, visualization, looker-studio

I've connected BigQuery tables to my Data Studio, created the report and embedded it to my site through iframe.
I like to have an option to refresh data on my report when I need it. Not by automatically interval or proceeding to my Data Studio account and do it manually.
The case it that:

1. I make some actions;
2. Data in BigQuery Tables changes;
3. I send some request to Data Studio API or do some other actions and data will update in my report.

My questions:

1. If there exist such possibility?
2. Maybe I can add some control to the Report which will act as the button Refresh in Data Studio account?
3. I can find the data freshness info badge, in the bottom right corner on the Data Studio site. Could I, at least, show it on my embedded report on my site.

[data freshness badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmfLT.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the data in the report, please press CRTL+SHIFT+E

I am quite sure that there is no way that a change in a BigQuery table triggers a refresh in Data Studio. Data Studio queries the data on request of its user and even caches them.

The API is for searching reports and permissions. The main goal of the API is that the admins see what the people are doing and can limit access to the reports. https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api/reference

In some extend a refresh can be done by a customer viz. Here is an example, in which a refresh interval of 30 sec is set, but can also be turned off in the edit mode.

https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/da9b1d78-02ff-48d5-8cb5-3086a3853319/page/CbSWC

You could build your own Viz that does the refresh and define a trigger yourself, e.g. the viz checks an url every 30 sec. and if this url content changes, the viz refreshes the report in data studio.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer. I will try and write a feedback here.

Comment: Thanks again, but I can't make this visualisation work.
when I'm clicking refresh - it does nothing.

> You could build your own Viz that does the refresh and define a trigger yourself, e.g. the viz checks an url every 30 sec. and if this url content changes, the viz refreshes the report in data studio.

This feature could be very useful in my case. Could you explain how and where I cud put the "trigger" logic and, the main question, how I can make Data Studion Report refreshing.